# Poor performance on high-end iMac 5K Retina (October 2015 model)

Tags: macos, imac, memory, virtual-memory

I've got an iMac that is performing quite poorly. The specs:

- OS X El Capitan
- 4.0 GHz quad-core (i7)
- 16 GB RAM

I've tried everything possible to figure out what's going on, to no avail. Typically the machine has a few Adobe apps running (Photoshop, Illustrator), and Google Chrome with a bunch of tabs. Performance becomes *horribly* bad, rendering Photoshop almost unusable. The odd thing I noticed is that swap starts going up (to 10 GB in some cases) even though the physical RAM is only half exhausted.

[image]

Unfortunately I captured this after Photoshop was closed (which seems to help some). But while Photoshop is open, "Mem" is up to about 9-10 GB, and "Swp" can go as high as 10-12 GB.

The Activity Monitor shows a relatively low memory pressure (still in the green), so I'm not sure what the issue is. This is a pretty high-powered machine that shouldn't be exhibiting this behavior. I'm not sure if Adobe is the problem, or there's something wrong with this computer. How do I start to troubleshoot this?

Just to elaborate on the poor performance: simple things take way too long, such as nudging a layer over, or zooming in (as in, over 8 seconds for a simple operation!).

Comment: May I ask what you are using in the screenshot you provided?

Comment: A command line utility called htop. (installable via Homebrew)

Comment: have you restarted the computer, and made sure "Reopen windows" is turned off?

Comment: Yep, I've done that.

Comment: I have a similar computer, and when using PS for extended durations of renders it can take an awfully long time as well. FWIW, I'd go into Photoshop's performance settings (Cmd+K) and tweak from there. One of the major factors that affect performance are cache levels and "optimise cache for".

Comment: Just to add, the main limiting factor of PS performance is memory. I'm not sure why, but PS certainly consumes a lot of memory when open for long and performing intensive tasks. The swap behavior you are noticing is perfectly normal when using PS.

Comment: Also, memory pressure only indicates how much "stress" your memory is under: what you should be looking at is the "actual memory usage". This is usually close to the maximum amount available (16 GB in your case) when things start to slow down.

Comment: Just edited my post to explain what goes on. But basically really simple operations that should take a second or less wind up taking 5 seconds, sometimes 10 seconds or more. Really messed up!